# Having Internet access issues on single computer each day. Clears up after reboot the next day

Tags: windows, internet

I’m having a problem with my desktop computer that I cannot solve.

I’m running Windows 10 version 1903. The problem is limited to a single computer. All other devices on the network are working fine.

About a month ago, I started having problems accessing the internet first thing in the morning. No browser could connect, nor Outlook, nor my internet speed tester. A restart fixes the issue until the next day. Something happens overnight that breaks it.

I have my backups set to run at 4:00am, but I disabled that and the problem still occurs. I’ve tried all the things I could find by Googling; flush DNS, etc… to no avail. This happens wireless or wired, no difference. I even purchased a new Wi-Fi card with the same result.

I haven’t tried accessing the router, but I have a WD My Cloud attached to the router and I cannot access that when I’m having the issue. I’ve tried hardcoding the DNS servers and that didn’t fix the problem. I am not running any virtualization. Some limited pinging tests only results in a timeout.

A couple of days ago, I accidentally left Chrome open all night and through the next day. When I got home Chrome had great internet, but anything else I opened couldn’t connect.

Any help would be appreciated. I’m very close to doing a clean install.

Comment: Just to make sure, it's limited to this one computer and other devices on your network still have internet while the computer doesn't?

Comment: When you can't access the Internet, can you access the router? Can you access other machines on your local network? I'd suggest you get to the failed condition and do some troubleshooting to see exactly what's wrong. Do you still have a correct assigned IP address? Can you ping the router? Can you ping outside by IP address?

Comment: To start with, which operating system, and which release number, is used? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: When you did your ping test, were you pinging a DNS name or an IP address? Try to ping 8.8.8.8 and see what that does.

Comment: Your symptoms are really strange, especially the one where Chrome could still connect while others could not. Could you also check the task manager for network utilization, CPU, and memory usage? And Windows Update to check if it is trying to download a big update, which sometimes also makes my connection to other stuff drop. Lastly, try launching the Microsoft Troubleshooter (Control Panel --> Troubleshooting --> Network and Internet). You never know, you might get lucky and have it detect and solve it for you.

Comment: Task manager really shows no tasks utilizing a lot of anything. Pretty nominal stuff. I've tried the Network Troubleshooter and it says it couldn't determine the problem, but check the connections. If I wasn't bald already, this would make me so. Definitely strange symptoms.

Comment: Did you do a full virus/malware scan? If you have a third party antivirus, did you try disabling any firewall?

Comment: Really far stretch: do you use Linux under WSL? There are some known issues with recent versions that if an application under WSL tries to open sockets in a certain way, it never releases resources, and eventually starves all of windows from the ability to open new sockets and you get the behavior you're describing. In my case it happened to be the status line in the byobu app consuming a few sockets every second as it ran, and I just disabled most of the status line options to resolve the issue.

Comment: I can't find the original reference where I learned about the WSL issue, but I think this is the same one: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3951

Comment: I've done many full virus and malware scans and all come up with no infected files. As far as a firewall goes, I haven't tried that. I should try that, but why would Chrome continue to work when it was left open and only the newly  opened programs had the problem then? I'm not messing around with Linux at all.

Comment: So this morning, I did as suggested since I knew I wouldn't have internet access. First thing I noticed before trying anything was that the icon in the system tray indicated that I didn't have internet access, but I was connected to my network (this was true yesterday as well which was the first time this happened). I pinged 8.8.8.8 and couldn't reach it, but 10.0.0.120 responded and I could ping that. Not sure what that is; the router maybe? Browser was stuck at resolving host. I disconnected the network and reconnected (not restart). I could now ping 8.8.8.8, but still no internet.Restart.

Comment: Now that I have internet access again, I can, of course, ping 8.8.8.8, but I can't reach 10.0.0.120 by pinging where I could before. Could that be my own computer? Sorry if that's a dumb question. This is getting into new territory for me.

Comment: One more comment. Before the restart and reconnect, when I was first attempting to ping 8.8.8.8, 10.0.0.120 responded with destination unreachable. Now that I'm back up with internet I get a similar response from a different address when I ping the 120. That different address shows as my IPv4 address when I do a ipconfig /all.

Comment: New symptom. Internet access randomly stopped while in active use. Disconnected from Wi-Fi and reconnected (no restart) and everything was fine. This may have happened once  before, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I should also add that I turned off the firewall (Norton) and it had no effect.

Comment: So, again, the internet lost connection randomly in the middle of using, bu this time it restored itself after a few seconds. I should also add that I installed the new ASUS Wi-Fi card on Saturday and have been using that ever since. My internet is 3x faster than what it was in the past, but the new card did not fix the issue I'm having.